# R command to view package readme.md

Tags: r

There is `utils::news(package="mypack")` to open the NEWS file.

Is there also a command to open the README.md file of an R package?

Comment: If you look at the installed packages, there's usually no such file; people write them for GitHub. There is `packageDescription`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I confused something in my memory there: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2016q4/001178.html . I will now use a regular vignette.